# Why do we expect isometries of bulk side to be equivalent to symmetries of the CFT?

Tags: symmetry, representation-theory, research-level, ads-cft, holographic-principle

One can clearly see that the AdS bulk isometries form the $SO(d,2)$ symmetry of the $d$ dimensional CFT explicitly. Why does this occur: why don't the isometries of the spacetimes match up or the symmetries of the theory on both side match up in the statement of AdS/CFT? We can see it doesn't, but why would we naturally want to identify isometries of some spacetime and not the symmetries of the theory defined on it with symmetries of a theory on another lower dimensional spacetime and not its isometries? The same question remains for identification of Killing spinors on the AdS side and SUSYs on the CFT side: why are they identified?